# Is there any way to create a Floating Icon/button on Outlook VSTO for C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am pretty new to VSTO so just wondering if we could create a custom floating icon on Outlook just like the image here where Grammarly icon can be seen. On click of the icon, a new Winform window will open. I have the form part which will open, but not sure about the floating icon, if this can be accomplished. Any idea on how this can be achieved will help. Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no publicly available API to do that. Grammarly uses low level Windows API to place its UI on top of Outlook windows. You can retrieve HWND of an Outlook `Inspector` object by casting it to `IOleWindow` and calling `IOleWindow.GetWindow`. Once you have the HWND, you can override its window-proc, make your controls children of that window, etc.

Answer (score 1):

VSTO doesn't provide anything for that. You need to use a raw Windows API functions to get the job done. Looks like a child window is created for the floating button. See [Using Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-windows) for more information.

Or the editor control can be subclassed. If a control does almost everything you want, but you need a few more features, you can change or add features to the original control by subclassing it. A subclass can have all the features of an existing class as well as any additional features you want to give it. Read more about that in the [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) article.